# Progress bar according to countdown

Tags: javascript, css

I want to display a progress bar based on a countdown of 7 minutes that is displayed in a div: `<div id = "quiz-time-left"> 0:06:24 </ div>`

I need if the page is reloaded don´t reset the progress bar. Would it be possible with CSS and a script that the bar represents what the timer displays?

I use this css progress bar:

```
 #quiz-time-left {    
width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: progreso 420s linear;
            animation: progreso 420s linear;
color: #eb7260;
background: #eb7260;
 }
#page-mod-quiz-summary #quiz-timer {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: -50px;
}
#quiz-timer {
border: 2px solid #eb7260;
text-indent: -9999px;
display:block;
    font-size: 0px;
    height: 35px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes progreso {
    0% {
        width: 100%;;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes progreso {
    0% {
        width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

html

```
<div id="quiz-timer" role="timer" aria-atomic="true" aria-relevant="text" style="display: block;">Time left: <div id="quiz-time-left">0:06:41</div></div>
```

Thank you. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is using localStorage to store the current state of the timer and each second decrease this number.

So when the page has finished loading, test if localStorage is undefined, if it is then set it to 420. If localStorage != undefined then resume the animation from the time stored in localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement something like this:

Make sure you save time left in localStorage

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(timeLeft) {
       localStorage.setItem('countDown', timeLeft);
    }
```

When loading the page check if there is an item called `countDown` and resume countDown with the value:

```
if(localStorage['countDown'] {
    resumeCountdown(localStorage.getItem('countDown');
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michelangelo! But I do not know how to implement it, I want to use it in a quiz in Moodle 3.1, I would appreciate some clue or advice to help me